# How to run code in finally block but only after after try block succeeded?

Tags: python, flask

I am building a simple flask app and I was wondering if I could perform one action like we do in the `finally` block after a `try-except` block but ONLY if the try succeeded and AFTER a `return` statement in the try block.

I tried `else` but `else` does not execute after `return`.

This is short of what I would like to do:

```
def delete(self,pet_id):
    if pet_id:
        pet = None
        try:
            pet = [pet for pet in self.pets if pet.get("id")==pet_id][0]
            return jsonify({"pet": pet}), HTTPStatus.OK
        except Exception as exc:
            return (
            f"The pet id provided: {pet_id}, does not exist",
            HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        )
        else:
            self.pets.remove(pet)
```

Comment: You can achieve that with a boolean variable, but the entire point of  using`finally` is  that it is executed regardless if an exception was raised. Just put the`return` statement inside the `else` block.

Comment: @DeepSpace the `else` block does not work though this is what I described in the question. How can you run something after a return statement?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't put the `return` statement **inside** the `else` block (obviously **after** `self.pets.remove(pet)`)

Comment: because nothing will be executed after a `return` statement. Only `finally` executes after a `return` statement. My question (which people seem to downvote without understanding) is how can I run something after a `return` statement only if the `try` block succeeded

Comment: A return statement will always exit our of a function, which bypasses all remaining code. Things that still get executed after a return are the exit block of context managers, but not code in the function itself.

Comment: Why you want to run 'something' after return and **not** before returning ?

Comment: @joanis no finally is executed after a return statement! I want to o what finally does but only if `try` succeeded

Comment: I'm not sure if you are ignoring my suggestion on purpose so I'll ask again. Why can you not put the `return `statement in the `else` block after `self.pets.remove(pet)` ? Without using `finally` or some other hacky, over-engineered, unmaintainable solutions it is impossible to execute anything after `return`

Comment: @DeepSpaceI am not ignoring it. I am not sure you understood what I want to do. I want to delete the object after I returned it. Or in some other case you might want to do some clean up after the return is called. These are routine things. That is why finally exists. But how can it run only if try suceeds?

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not answer the question as asked, since I'm not using a `finally` block, but I still think it's worth pointing out that a `finally` block is not necessary to solve this problem.

Python uses reference counting, so when you save the value to return in `pet`, you've increased the reference count by one. That means that when you delete `pet` from `self.pets` with the line `self.pets.remove(pet)`, the object is not cleared in memory and you can still return it on the next line.

I think the logic you want, "do X only if the try succeeds" does not belong in the finally block, it belongs inside the `try` block.

Thus, I recommend restructuring your code as follows:

```
def delete(self,pet_id):
    if pet_id:
    try: 
        pet = [pet for pet in self.pets if pet.get("id")==pet_id][0]
        self.pets.remove(pet)
        return jsonify({"pet": pet}), HTTPStatus.OK
    except Exception as exc:
        return (
            f"The pet id provided: {pet_id}, does not exist",
            HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        )
```

Comment: but this wont work if i lets say wanted to `del` the object I am returning. Which you can do with finally. Which runs after return. But it seems there is not finally for success only, which is weird..

Comment: @KZiovas: How you would not be able to use `del` (please edit your question) ? Somehow I think you are overcomplicating things ...

Comment: @MauriceMeyer no it is a simple thing :-) people seem to get upset in stack overflow when someone asks something they feel they should know but they dont and it annoys them more than they re willing to help. I want a short of conditional `finally` tool that only runs after `try ` has succeeded and after a return statement. You could not use `del` before return because if you delete an object and then you try to return it you ll get an error. Which you dont get with finally.

Comment: @KZiovas Using "del" on a variable deletes the variable which holds a reference to an object. Lists also hold references, therefore removing an item only deletes the reference, too. If the object is referenced anywhere else yet, it isn't removed. Therefore it doesn't matter if "del" happens before or after "return".

Comment: I'm not sure why I got downvoted. I think this code does the same thing as the accepted answer. `self.pets.remove(pet)` does not actually delete `pet`, it only takes it out of the list, so you can do it before the return without any problem.